# SQLite and UI update order on android?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

Hello this is a simple design question for better practices:

Example and Context:
I'm creating an app that shows a list of items in a players stash. For this i need following requests:

1. Ask for all items IDS, one request.
2. Look for each ID  and inside each response i'll get the ICON link. As many requests as ITEMS here
3. Request each ICON. As many request at items here.

All this will be presented on a Recyclerview list with cardviews and saved locally to the device database.

The question is: In which order should i do this???

Option A: get items IDs > Save to DB > Read DB > get ITEM OBJECTS > Save to DB > Read Database > GET ICON IMAGES > FILL UI LIST

Option B: get ONE item ID > get ONE item Object > get ONE item icon > present to UI > save Item Object to Database

ON both cases i will have timeout or try cach for items that fail to get.
ON both cases in the future I will only request ICONs for existant items or full requests for new items in stash.

If you have another suggestion or approach feel free to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i was you, I would create the loading so that the user sees items without the user having to wait too long.

I would (asynchronously) do the following:

1. Get Item IDs
2. Request all items. When a request completes, add a item with a placeholder ICON to the UI
3. For each requested item, request the ICON. When a ICON request completes, update the UI and save it to database

While the objects are loading, you can show a spinning progress bar on top of the RecyclerView, so the user sees the progess bar spinning, and the items being added one by one in the background. You can even add an animation very easily to the RecyclerView, so your app looks even cooler while loading.